# I have an issue with my wallet. it is giving me fatal error

Tags: wallet, wallet.dat, wallet-recovery

Sorry to ask it here because I can not find a better place..
This question is related to my Dogecoin wallet ...

I accumulated some dogecoin in the past, but I have not been able to recover them for weeks but finally today I managed to recover them.

However, when I closed my wallet, I was never been able to open as the wallet until now as it keeps giving me this error message

A fatal error occurred. Dogecoin can no longer continue safely and will quit.

```
EXCEPTION: St13runtime_error
CWalletDB::ListAccountCreditDebit(): cannot create DB cursor
D:\ML\Other Files\Altcoin Projects\Dogecoin Project\Program\Dogecoin\dogecoin-qt.exe in Runaway exception
```

[Link to error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7k40.jpg)

I don't really know what to do now. Please help me

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the dogecoin client?